# How to Get 1 Data of 3 Data in Firebase Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 3 data with diffrent ID in firebase.

Example :

```
Data :
  - ABC 
     Lat: 12345
     Lng: 23124
  - DEF 
     Lat: 23324
     Lng: 43553
  - GHI 
     Lat: 23424
     Lng: 12343
```

How can i get `Lat` which is 12345 from ID `ABC`, i wish i could show it with Toast trigger by Button.

Comment: You will be getting this data in json format and then compare to get the Lat or Lng ?

Comment: Lat and Lng its ok, just only one of them.

Comment: @noogui Please read [Title Case or Sentence Case?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252624)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your snapshot you have to get your child and your element just like this :

```
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Data"); //Init your ref at Data
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                       
            String lat = messageSnapshot.child("ABC").child("Lat").getValue().toString(); //acces to ABC => Lat
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + lat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //print here
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
```

Comment: `database`.getreferences is red

Comment: updated i forgot the instance of the database ;) @husen

Comment: `messageSnapsot` is red XD

Comment: edited, my bad aha. You can put addValueListener whenever you want like in a onClickListener ;) @husen

Comment: same like answer above, i got crash too

Comment: As Alex asked, what is the error in "Run" section when the app stop working ?? @husen

Comment: It work know, how if there is 2 marker, location marker based on lat and lng, how can i show Lat lang abc when i click marker abc, also with maker efg.

Comment: You just have to implement a for loop to get your value for each field. Replace the specification child "ABC" by "" and the specification "Lat" by "". That's it. Thanks for validated.

Answer (score 1):

To toast a message that contains the `lat` value, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference abcRef = rootRef.child("Data").child("ABC");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double lat = dataSnapshot.child("Lat").getValue(Double.class);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + lat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
abcRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be: `12345`

Comment: Can i put ValueEventListner inside `Button.setOnClickListner`? I try to put it but my app stop working.

Comment: Yes, you can. It stopped working giving an error. What is that error?

Comment: No error just when i click the button, app stop working

Comment: If it is a crash (the app stops working) it means that you have an exception in the logcat. What is that exception? Is written in red.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you solved the issue?

Comment: 04-05 16:17:24.507 2877-3324/? E/SLocation: Invalid data -5

Comment: Beside the fact that in your schema, your lat and long are stored as doubles `Lat: 12345` and not as strings as in you accepted answer, you're welcome! `Lat: "12345"`, see the quotation marks? This is how the values are stored as strings. Is different than in your schema :|